# Is there a standard way to validate constraints between multiple items in an array?

Tags: java, spring, validation

I'm working on a RESTful Spring boot microservice, with a POST endpoint  which accepts an `Order`.

An `Order` contains, among other fields, an array of `Product`, which for the purpose of this example has two fields, `id` and `parameter`, both String.

A requirement I've received is to implement validation on the array of `Product`, such that, for instance:

**IF** products contains an item with ID 123,
**THEN** it cannot also contain an item with an ID [234, 345].

and

**IF** products contains an item with ID 789,
**THEN** any product with ID in [456, 567] must have a non-null parameter field.

I've implemented these as custom validation annotations, with two methods `conditionalOn` and `required` - and then a validator for each annotation which implements the logic for each assertion: e.g. for the first,

```
if (order.getProducts().stream().anyMatch(p -> annotation.conditionalOn().equals(p.getId()))) {
  return order.getProducts().stream().noneMatch(p -> annotation.required().equals(p.getId()));
}
```

But the field on `Order` ends up having a huge selection of annotations on it, some duplicated, as there are multiple of the same constraint. As a simplified example,

```
class Order {
  @CombinationsNotAllowed({
    @CombinationNotAllowed(conditionalOn = "123", required = { "234", "345" }),
    @CombinationNotAllowed(conditionalOn = "321", required = { "432", "543" })
    // ... etc etc
  })
  ParametersRequired({
    @ParameterRequired(conditionalOn = "789", required = { "456", "567" }),
    @ParameterRequired(conditionalOn = "987", required = { "654", "765" })
    // ... etc etc
  })
  // further annotations
  private List<Product> products;
}
```

I'm also conscious that these constraints *may* change, though I don't expect them to.

Is there a more standard way of defining these constraints across the items in `Order#getProducts`?

Comment: This is a terrible way to implement such a requirement. Validation should be externalized into a utility.  Create an interface for the methods you'll need to valiate the Order/Products, implement some Rule classes based on that interface and then pass the Order through the rules. If a violation occurs, throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use composition to wrap a HashSet (or HashMap) and implement Iterable (or Collection). In your `add()` and `addAll()` methods verify your constraints. Since HashTables have O(1) lookup, it will be quite performant.

In terms of mapping incompatibilities, you can have a map of lists, where the key is product id and value is all incompatible products.

Then you can make annotation that will verify the required elements.